# Cannot access this.props.action using React-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm building a react native app using redux. I cannot seem to gain access to this.props.cameraTypeChanged() action, though when I console.log this.props they seem to be coming through fine.

The error I'm receiving is...

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.cameraTypeChanged')
```

See code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Camera, Permissions } from 'expo';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {cameraTypeChanged, cameraPermission} from "../actions";

class Photo extends Component {

    flipCamera() {
        console.log("flip camera");
        this.props.cameraTypeChanged('back');
    }


  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={this.props.cameraType}>
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                    }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{
                            flex: 0.1,
                            alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                        }}
                        onPress={this.flipCamera}
                    >
                        <Text
                            style={{ fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 10, color: 'white' }}>
                            {' '}Flip{' '}
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </Camera>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        cameraType: state.cameraScreen.cameraType,
        hasPermission: state.cameraScreen.hasPermission,
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { cameraTypeChanged, cameraPermission })(Photo);
```

Comment: maybe add mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => { cameraTypeChanged: () =>{
dispatch(cameraTypeChanged());
}}

Comment: and add mapDispatchToProps as second argument of connect

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<TouchableOpacity
   style={{
      flex: 0.1,
      alignSelf: 'flex-end',
      alignItems: 'center',
   }}
   onPress={this.flipCamera.bind(this)}
>
```

it seems that `flipCamera` function is invoked on another object - not your component.

Answer (score 0):

Try using arrow function to bind the `this` context

`flipCamera = () => {
  console.log("flip camera");
  this.props.cameraTypeChanged('back');
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the implementation of `cameraTypeChanged`?

If you check the [react-redux docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#implementing-container-components), the second argument of `connect` function often called `mapDispatchToProps` is a function that:

> receives the dispatch() method and returns callback props that you want to inject into the presentational component.

In your code you provided `connect` function an object as a 2nd argument:

```
{ cameraTypeChanged, cameraPermission }
```

Try to change it to:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      cameraTypeChanged: (args) => dispatch(cameraTypeChanged(args)),
      // other actions respectively
    }
};
```